# How does one get back the money from a blocked account?

Tags: germany, banking

For purposes of studying in Germany, one has to show a certain amount of money in a bank account known as "Sperrkonto", which periodically deposits some amount of money per month to our German bank account. If for whatever reason I were to decide to give up, how could I receive the money deposited in the Sperrkonto back? What would be the procedure?

I tried googling but I can't find anything.

Comment: It is blocked, you cannot get it back all at once.

Comment: Have you seen https://www.germany.info/us-en/sperrkonto/388600? It doesn't provide many details but it suggests you need the permission from the authority in charge of your visa (German consulate or foreigner's authority). So the procedure should be something like this: Asking them to invalidate your visa or wait for it to expire, then ask them for permission (basically confirming you are not in Germany anymore). Alternatively, you could always draw from it monthly until you have exhausted the money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The escrow account you have is usually blocked by some authority, e.g. Ausländerbehörde. For example, you usually get a paper from them and bank creates escrow account for you and locks it in the name of that authority.

If you need to unlock it, you just need another paper from that authority issuing "the unlock".